# Responsive website works on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, responsive-design

This is my first time building a responsive website and so far so good. But the problem right now is that it's working fine on google chrome (tested on phone and toggle device mode) but not on Firefox. 
If you open this in device mode you can see what I mean (Firefox).

Anyone know what the problem is?

I don't think the html code is necessary and the css code. Cause I think the problem lies in the first row code, but just in case I put the css code up.

EDIT: in 320 x 480 pixels

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait){ /*Mobiel portrait modus*/

html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial;
    height: 100%; 
}

.link 
{ 
    color: inherit; 
    text-decoration: none;
} 

.top
{
    position: fixed; 
    z-index:9999;
    background: #80c217; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #80c217 0%, #80c217 37%, #80c217 40%, #a1d54f 66%, #7cbc0a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#80c217), color-stop(37%,#80c217), color-stop(40%,#80c217), color-stop(66%,#a1d54f), color-stop(100%,#7cbc0a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #80c217 0%,#80c217 37%,#80c217 40%,#a1d54f 66%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #80c217 0%,#80c217 37%,#80c217 40%,#a1d54f 66%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #80c217 0%,#80c217 37%,#80c217 40%,#a1d54f 66%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #80c217 0%,#80c217 37%,#80c217 40%,#a1d54f 66%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* W3C */
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
h1, h2 
{
    display: inline;
}

.menu
{
    width: 70px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: -220px;
}
h1
{
    font-size: 30px;
}
h2
{
    font-size: 18px;
}

.logo
{
    float:right;
    width: 150px;
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-right: 75px;

}

.title
{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 75px;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

.navbar
{
    margin-top: 199px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 200;
}

.nav 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -4px;

}

.nav li
{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top:1px solid white;
}

.nav li:last-child
{
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
}

.head2
{
    font-size: 40px;

}

.links
{
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.middle
{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #ccd3c3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 950px;
    font-size: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.middlemachtiging
{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #ccd3c3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 710px;
    font-size: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.middleprijzen
{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #ccd3c3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1150px;
    font-size: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.text
{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.auto
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

footer
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #9ffe62;
    color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

footer p
{
    padding-top: 45px;
}

}

.pricetable
{
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure if a desktop(?) Firefox supports `orientation:portrait` …?

Comment: Hi, yes but I've tried it on phone too but it will look the same as in Firefox device mode.

Comment: Well just remove that part of the media query and see if it works in your FF then …

Comment: It gives the same result.

Comment: Well then we’ll need more details. What specifically doesn’t work?

Comment: If you open my link in device mode in Firefox it looks more zoomed in then in Google Chrome device mode, which causes the logo to disorder. Is it possible that it's because of a viewport tag? I've used:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=620, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: Your media query seems to be fine http://jsfiddle.net/dpbuaykk/ works fine in both FF and chrome in normal mode

Comment: Why are you setting `width=620` in the viewport meta, and then have a media query for `min-width: 320px`? And `user-scalable=no` is a really bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's because Firefox doesn't work with the meta name="viewport" tag? Is that possible?

Comment: Ah, I found out that when I put in width=320 instead of 620 it looks the same as in Firefox, is there a way to use the tag for Firefox too?

I put the tag otherwise it autoscales on mobile phone, very annoying.

Comment: Why are you setting width to a static number in the viewport meta tag?